# Sed not working

Tags: sed

I have a file with multiple lines containing a string : `; Ltd` that I want to change to `Ltd`. I tried :

```
sed -e 's/; Ltd/ Ltd/ig' file
```

Sometimes it is also `; ltd` so I added the `i` tag for case insensitivity but it won't work for either. Tried to add and remove `-e` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as it will find both upper and lower case `L`:

```
sed 's/; [Ll]td/ Ltd/g' file
```

Don't forget to add the `-i` to actually write the changes to the file.

```
sed -i 's/; [Ll]td/ Ltd/g' file
```

Comment: oh it was the `-i` missing, I'm barely a sed user.